# load previously visited page

Tags: android, webview

I'm using WebView.goBack() to navigate to previously visited page and that works fine. My problem is: WebView is always loading (from internet - and that takes several seconds) previous page as if it's visited for the first time.
 I mean, if i visited web page 3 seconds ago, I suppose it's cached somewhere and want it to show up immediately by clicking on back button. Already tried WebSettings.setcachemode(), but doesn't help.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have more to do.
That works for me(or maybe not. I have a realy fast connection :-) ):

```
viewer.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8); 
viewer.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/your_apppackage/cache"‌​);
viewer.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true); 
viewer.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I think that is due to your fast connection :) I've already tried this code.